# Java reflection - Get values from class instance field

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to create an some cheat for Minecraft. For this I decided to use reflection and agents. At the first stage, a question arose.
I have Minecraft.class class. This class has getMinecraft() method that returns the instance of Minecraft. And this instance has player field. From this field, i need to get posX variable. I think I did not explain very clearly, so here is an example code of what I want to do:

```
final net.minecraft.client.Minecraft mc = net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getMinecraft();
System.out.println(mc.player.posX);
```

And now, is it possible to somehow implement this through reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the following reflection methods:

- [`Class.forName(String className)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)

  - [`getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-)

    - [`invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)
  - [`getField(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-)

    - [`get(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-)

```java
Class<?> minecraftClass = Class.forName("net.minecraft.client.Minecraft");
Object mc = minecraftClass.getMethod("getMinecraft")
                          .invoke(null);
Object player = mc.getClass().getField("player")
                  .get(mc);
Object posX = player.getClass().getField("posX")
                    .get(player);
System.out.println(posX);
```